# Angular Material data table sorting not working/no arrows shown

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to implement sorting on my angular material data table.

It's displaying the data correctly but the sorting doesn't work, it doesn't even show the small arrow next to the header to indicate it's being sorted.

Here's my component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Project, Activity, LearningObjective } from '../../models';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-activities',
  templateUrl: './activities.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./activities.component.scss']
})
export class ActivitiesComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  projects          : Array<Project>;
  loading           : boolean = false;
  displayedColumns  : string[] = ['name', 'goal', 'date', 'actions'];
  dataSource;

  constructor(
    private http          : HttpClient,
    private toastr        : ToastrService,
    public authService    : AuthService,
    private router        : Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProjects();
  }

  getProjects() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.http.get<Project[]>('projects')
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        this.projects = response;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.projects);
        this.loading = false;
      },
      err => {
        this.toastr.error(err.error.message, 'Error');
        this.loading = false;
      }
    )
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

And my html

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="goal">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Goal </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.goal}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <div class="button-row">
          <button  mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="loading ">
              <i class="fa fa-edit " *ngIf="!loading"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin " *ngIf="loading"></i>
            </button>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="deleteProject(element._id)" [disabled]="loading">
              <i class="fa fa-trash " *ngIf="!loading"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin " *ngIf="loading"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

How do I correctly implement the sort in this case? Can't click the table headers like in a working example so I'm wondering what is missing here.

Comment: Make sure you're importing either `NoopAnimationsModule` or `BrowserAnimationsModule` from `@angular/platform-browser/animations` in order for the data show in time and the arrows show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It most likely won't work because your async request to load the data in the `ngOnInit` takes longer than for the component lifecycle hook `ngAfterViewInit` to be called. Therefore your `dataSource` is still undefined and the setting of the sorting won't work.

You could initially create a new `MatTableDataSource` with an empty array to get around this problem. When you declare the datasource in your component:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
```

And then in your `getProjects` simply do this:

```
this.dataSource.data = this.projects;
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

> Check out the
>   [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-78ulml?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
>   for a solution. I had to mock the HTTP request and used a delay to
>   simulate the request.

Comment: Hi, Good day ..

Comment: is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78125743/matsortheader-does-work-is-because-it-is-added-to-async-block ? Thanks.