# Sorting in angular mat-table is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8, mat-table

I can't sort values in my angular material table by price. The screen of table is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP1w8.png). So the arrow to sort is visible but it's not working. I suppose (maybe I'm wrong) the problem could be connected with 'dataSource' - I'm not sure if I set it correctly but I don't get any errors.

> product-list.html

```
  <div class="flex-child green">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Type product name</mat-label>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex. ium" #input>
    </mat-form-field>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" matSortActive="price"
       matSortDirection="desc" matSortDisableClear>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Id</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.id}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Category</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.category}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Price</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.price}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="popularity">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Popularity</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.popularity}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
        <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter {{input.value}} </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

> product-list.ts

```
export class Product {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public category: string,
    public price: number,
    public popularity: number
  ) {
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.scss']
})

export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[]
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'category', 'price', 'popularity'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Product>(this.products);
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productDataService.getAllProducts('rabarbar').subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.products = response;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
      }
    )
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  constructor(private productDataService: ProductDataService) {
  }
}
```

I'm sending data from backend, here is response:

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, name: "carrot", category: "vegatables", price: 12, popularity: 1}
1: {id: 2, name: "apple", category: "vegatables", price: 8, popularity: 1}
2: {id: 3, name: "banana", category: "vegatables", price: 9, popularity: 1}
3: {id: 4, name: "lemon", category: "vegatables", price: 5, popularity: 1}
4: {id: 5, name: "strawberry", category: "vegatables", price: 11, popularity: 1}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950684/angular-material-data-table-sorting-not-working-no-arrows-shown

Comment: omg thank you so much, it is working